# jQuery submit won't submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have written this script but the form will not submit when 'No' is pressed on the dialog.

This is the page where the script is live:
http://www.absoluteglazing.co.uk/quotation?item=walkon

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't work it out.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { // Document ready function

$('#quoteform').submit(function(event) {  // Submit form function

    event.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting

// Variable declaration
    var GetLength = $('#length').val(); // Length variable
    var GetWidth = $('#width').val(); // Width variable
    var GetLengthUnit = $('#length_unit').val(); // Length variable
    var GetWidthUnit = $('#width_unit').val(); // Width variable
    var GetNoPanes = $('input[name=nopanes]:checked').val(); // Number of panes variable
    var GetLocation = $('#thelocation').val(); // Location variable
    var GetAntislip = $('#antislip:checked').val(); // Antislip checked variable
    var GetFirerated = $('#firerated:checked').val(); // Fire Rated checked variable
    var GetSolarcontrol = $('#colarcontrol:checked').val(); // Solar Control checked variable
    var GetLengthConverted
    var GetWidthConverted
    var GetPaneLength
    var GetPaneWidth
// End of ariable declaration

if(GetLength < GetWidth) { // If length is less than width
    $('#length').val(GetWidth); // Set length to width
    $('#width').val(GetLength); // Set width to length
    var GetLengthTemp = GetWidth;
    var GetWidthTemp = GetLength;
    GetLength = GetLengthTemp;
    GetWidth = GetWidthTemp;
} // End if length is less than width

if(!$.isNumeric(GetLength) || !$.isNumeric(GetWidth)) { // Check to see if length and width are numeric

    swal({  
    title: "Error!",   
    text: "Please enter a valid length and width",   
    type: "error",   
    confirmButtonColor: "#f36e21",
    confirmButtonText: "OK" });

} else { // If length and width are valid then continue

    if(GetLengthUnit == 'cm') { // cm to mm conversion
        GetLengthConverted = GetLength * 10;
    } else if(GetLengthUnit == 'm') { // m to mm conversion
        GetLengthConverted = GetLength * 1000;
    } else if(GetLengthUnit == 'inches') { //inches to mm conversion
        GetLengthConverted = GetLength * 25.4;
    } else if(GetLengthUnit == 'feet') { // feet to mm
        GetLengthConverted = GetLength * 304.8;
    } else { // if in mm then no conversion needed
        GetLengthConverted = GetLength;
    }

    if(GetWidthUnit == 'cm') { // cm to mm conversion
        GetWidthConverted = GetWidth * 10;
    } else if(GetWidthUnit == 'm') { // m to mm conversion
        GetWidthConverted = GetWidth * 1000;
    } else if(GetWidthUnit == 'inches') { //inches to mm conversion
        GetWidthConverted = GetWidth * 25.4;
    } else if(GetWidthUnit == 'feet') { // feet to mm
        GetWidthConverted = GetWidth * 304.8;
    } else { // if in mm then no conversion needed
        GetWidthConverted = GetWidth;
    }

    if(GetNoPanes == 1) { // If one pane
        GetPaneLength = GetLengthConverted;
        GetPaneWidth = GetWidthConverted;
    } else if(GetNoPanes == 2) { // If two panes
        GetPaneLength = GetLengthConverted / 2;
        GetPaneWidth = GetWidthConverted;
    } else if(GetNoPanes == 3) { // If three panes
        GetPaneLength = GetLengthConverted / 3;
        GetPaneWidth = GetWidthConverted;
    } else if(GetNoPanes == 4) { // If four panes
        GetPaneLength = GetLengthConverted / 2;
        GetPaneWidth = GetWidthConverted / 2;
    } else { // If five or more panes
        GetPaneLength = 5000; // Use 5000 for error checking 5 panes or more
        GetPaneWidth = 5000; // Use 5000 for error checking 5 panes or more
    }

    if(GetPaneLength > 2950 || GetPaneWidth > 2400) {
        swal({  
        title: "Are you sure?",   
        text: "The size of glass panes in your quotation are quite large and will increase the cost. Would you like to split this into more panes of glass?",   
        type: "info",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",   
        cancelButtonText: "No",   
        closeOnConfirm: true,   
        closeOnCancel: false },
        function(isConfirm){  
        if (isConfirm) {     
            // Nothing, just close dialog
        } else {  
            alert('Just testing something is happening');   
            $('#quoteform').submit();
        } });
    }

} // End check to see if length and width are numeric

}); // End submit form function

}); // End document ready function
```

Comment: You should initiate the function on a click instead of submit `$('#quoteform').submit(function(event) {` here. Probably `$('#quoteform').click(function(event) {` or just use `.on` and then submit. Note: `#quoteform` here should be the id of the submit input button, which you should change to a button, remove the submit type from that button. and then initiate form submit `$('#formid').submit();` inside the function.

Comment: @Maz: **Never** use `click` for form submits. You bypass keypress-based submission of the form.

Comment: You are submitting a form normally using `.submit()` you are just using `.click` to validate the form :)

Comment: @Maz: *Again:* Keyboard submission of the form will bypass the click handler. *Do not use `click` with forms*. Always use the `submit` event.

Comment: I think you are missing my point, which I might be missing yours too. Any pointer where I can look up on what you are saying ? In anycase, I was just suggesting a solution to the problem he is having.

Comment: @Maz: I understand your suggestion, but am simply trying to say that is a really *really* bad idea as it can be easily bypassed and not work if the form submit is triggered via keyboard (i.e. `Enter`) and not a mouse click :)

Comment: From [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) they too have a `.click()` function triggering `.submit()`. @TrueBlueAussie: care to explain why it is bad ? Sorry, if I am asking very noob questions.

Comment: @Maz: Their example if specifically for "We can trigger the event manually when another element is clicked". Which is not the same as "I will catch click on the submit button". For the final time: *your `click` handler will not fire if the form is submitted in response to keyboard*

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I am not catching click on submit button, I asked specifically to remove button type submit. Do read my previous suggestion again. If you are thinking that I have asked for ""I will catch click on the submit button" you are WRONG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your manual submit code `$('#quoteform').submit();`, which when invoked will again call the submit event handler again which will in turn prevent the default action causing recursive calls of the handler.

Instead you can try to call the dom element's submit method which wouldn't invoke the submit event handler.

```
$('#quoteform')[0].submit();
```